# How to get end time of the current year

Tags: sql, postgresql

example, this year is 2020, and the end time of the year islike this

'2020-12-31 23:59:59'

How to select those kind of value?

select endtimeofthisyear()

Comment: If you are planning to use this e.g. with a `<=` operator it's typically better to use the first of january next year at midnight together with `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want last second of current year. Compute it as 1 s subtracted from first second of next year.

```sql
select date_trunc('year', now()) + interval '1 year' - interval '1 second'
```

Note: currently this is equivalent to concatenating hardcoded string ...23:59:59. If PG handled leap seconds (which AFAIK currently doesn't), it is more likely the leap second would be taken into consideration using expression above.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of no good reason for looking for the last second of a year.  If you are filtering by year, then use:

```
where date >= '2020-01-01' and date < '2021-01-01'
```

If you are constructing a table with time-tiling -- effective and end dates -- then make the first date inclusive and the second exclusive.  Then the next effective date is the previous row's end date -- there is no gap.

You would query a table as:

```
where <some value> >= eff_dt and <some value> < end_dt
```

One issue in trying to get the last "moment" is that time is continuous (well, I suppose that is a fundamental question about the universe, but it is how we measure it).  If you aim for the last second, you will miss times that occur during the last second, such as `2020-12-31 23:59:59.555`.

Answer (score 0):

Since every year ends on the 31.12. 23:59:59, just get the current_date, extract the year and add it.

`date_trunc('year', now()) + '-12-31 23:59:59'`